# T-SQL SELECT DISTINCT & ROW_NUMBER() OVER Ordering Problem

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, paging

I'm trying to select DISTINCT rows from a view using ROW_NUMBER() OVER for paging.  When I switched the ORDER BY field from a SMALLDATETIME to INT I started getting weird results:

```
SELECT RowId, Title, HitCount FROM
( SELECT DISTINCT Title, HitCount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY HitCount DESC) AS RowId FROM ou_v_Articles T ) AS Temp
WHERE RowId BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

This query returns:

```
RowId | Title | HitCount
=======================
4  ---  9
1  ---  43
3  ---  11
2  ---  13
5  ---  0
```

The results are obviously not in the correct order.  I'm not sure what the problem is here,  but when I removed DISTINCT it orders them correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the RowId value you're getting correct? Perhaps you just need an ORDER BY RowId clause on the outer query?

Comment: Good call.  I should have seen that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Applying DISTINCT to a column list containing ROW_NUMBER() will always result in every row being distinct, as there is one ROW_NUMBER per row.

Comment: That would seem to make sense, except I'm not getting any duplicate rows in my results.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using an order by on the outer select and removing the OVER clause?

Comment: Well this query works fine:

SELECT Title, HitCount FROM
( SELECT DISTINCT Title, HitCount FROM ou_v_Articles T ) AS Temp ORDER BY HitCount DESC

Except I need the ROW_NUMBER for paging.