# How to implement paging in NHibernate with a left join query

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2008, hql

I have an NHibernate query that looks like this:

```
        var query = Session.CreateQuery(@"
              select o
              from Order o
                left join o.Products p
              where
                (o.CompanyId = :companyId) AND
                (p.Status = :processing)
              order by o.UpdatedOn desc")
              .SetParameter("companyId", companyId)
              .SetParameter("processing", Status.Processing)
              .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);

        var data = query.List<Order>();
```

I want to implement paging for this query, so I only return x rows instead of the entire result set.

I know about `SetMaxResults()` and `SetFirstResult()`, but because of the `left join` and `DistinctRootEntity`, that could return less than x Orders.

I tried `"select distinct o"` as well, but the sql that is generated for that (using the sqlserver 2008 dialect) seems to ignore the `distinct` for pages after the first one (I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293987/t-sql-select-distinct-row-number-over-ordering-problem#2294000) is the problem).

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean()) and get the data that is not the entity.

The other solution is that you change the query.
As I see you're returning Orders that have products which are processing.
So you could use exists statement. Check nhibernate manual at 13.11. Subqueries.

Comment: The `exists` idea is interesting... I will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

In these cases, it's best to do it in two queries instead of one:

1. Load a page of orders, without joins
2. Load those orders with their products, using the `in` operator

There's a slightly more complex example at http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/16/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate.aspx

Comment: For step #2, I guess you would manually build a list of IDs from the result in step #1.  Or is there a better/more concise way?

Comment: @evanhaas that was probably what I meant 4 years ago :-) but I think you can use a subquery and HQL paging.