# distinct and row_number do not work together

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get a list of unique names as well as a row count column so that it would look like this:

```
1 wilford building
2 oxford center
3 williams place
```

I need the distinct in there, so that I only get each building name once.

```
SELECT R.RowNum, 
       R.COLUMN_NAME
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY buildingName 
                              ORDER BY buildingName ) AS RowNum, 
           DISTINCT buildingName AS COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM cityStatus 
) AS R
```

But, as it is, it's not working.

Is it possible to use `DISTINCT` with `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Comment: Describe what "Not working" means. Error? Incorrect result?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121130/sql-query-distinct-with-row-number http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293987/t-sql-select-distinct-row-number-over-ordering-problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  buildingName,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY buildingName) AS RowNum
FROM cityStatus
GROUP BY buildingName
```

Comment: +1 - I prefer this method to my answer. I provided mine to answer the original question about using DISTINCT but I would use group by if I were doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Do the distinct first:

```
SELECT 
     row_number() over(partition by buildingName ORDER BY buildingName ) AS RowNum
    ,COLUMN_NAME 
from (
    select 
         DISTINCT buildingName AS COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM cityStatus
) as cityStatus
```

Comment: Why the most outer query? Same as the result it's selecting from?

Comment: True, thanks. I just grabbed his initial query and edited it. I'll remove it.